# what can I do to know parent's class name in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

my html look like this, and I want to retrieve "INFO" respectively.

```
<tr tabindex = "0">
<td data-name = "isu_srt_cd">"INFO"</td>
<td data-name = "com_abbrv">"INFO"</td>
...
<td data-name = "etf_obj">"INFO"</td>
</tr>
```

what I did so far is as follows,

```
for ana in soup.find_all("td"):
    if ana.parent.name == "tr":
        print(ana.get_text())
```

That's almost done, but I want to specify that parent's "tabindex" to be "0"

Comment: `if ana.parent.name == "tr" and ana.parent['tabindex'] == '0':`?

Comment: Thanks, logically, it should be done, and it seem it had found. But it has Error message, "KeyError: 'tabindex'" What should I do?

Comment: I used "try-except" and it seems gives me the wanted results. Thank you

Comment: you can also use: `if ana.parent.name == "tr" and 'tabindex' in ana.parent and ana.parent['tabindex'] == '0':`

Comment: You could *reverse* your search: `for tr in soup.find_all("tr", tabindex='0'): for ana in tr.find_all('td'): ...`

Comment: @ wwii , this works as well. Thank you so much~!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all the `<tr>`'s you are interested in then get all the `<td>`'s below it.

```
for tr in soup.find_all("tr", tabindex='0'):
    for ana in tr.find_all('td'):
        print(ana.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

```
for td in soup.select("tr[tabindex='0'] > td"):
    print(td.text)
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I've got a long loop to implement, so I will check this out later. Thank you again!!:)